# Can I get clickable menu item with submenu in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building system tray application with wxPython. It's easy to understand and works great so far, but I'm trying to get a non-standard behavior. I would like menu item to be clickable, but have a submenu at the same time. I know it's weird, but it would meet my needs the best. I want to execute default action on click, but have more options in submenu. The below code creates items just fine without submenu.

```
class TrackerMenuItem(wx.MenuItem):
    @staticmethod
    def create_and_bind(parent_menu, label, handler):
        menu_item = TrackerMenuItem(parent_menu, -1, label)
        parent_menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler, id=menu_item.GetId())
        parent_menu.Append(menu_item)
        return menu_item
```

But if I try to add submenu, binding stops working, and my item is just a parent for submenu (this is just a generic code for tests)

```
class TrackerMenuItem(wx.MenuItem):
    @staticmethod
    def create_and_bind(parent_menu, label, handler):
        menu_item = TrackerMenuItem(parent_menu, -1, label)
        submenu = wx.Menu()
        submenuitem = wx.MenuItem(submenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Submenu Item')
        submenu.Append(submenuitem)
        menu_item.SetSubMenu(submenu)
        parent_menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler, id=menu_item.GetId())
        parent_menu.Append(menu_item)
        return menu_item
```

Is it possible to work it around in a reasonable manner?

Comment: Does it work if you use `submenuitem.GetId()` when calling `Bind`?

Comment: @RobinDunn it works, but binds the subitem, not its parent.

Comment: EVT_MENU events are not sent for menu items with a submenu, but it might work with EVT_MENU_OPEN.